# How to use variable type other than string with the "GetCell"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to send data from my excel type, int, float, etc. But I can only send it as a string, instead of "ToString()" I can't change it to anything, how can I do that?

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult MostrarDados([FromForm] IFormFile ArquivoExcel)
        {
            Stream stream = ArquivoExcel.OpenReadStream();

            IWorkbook MeuExcel = null;

            if (Path.GetExtension(ArquivoExcel.FileName) == ".xlsx")
            {
                MeuExcel = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
            }
            else
            {
                MeuExcel = new HSSFWorkbook(stream);
            }

            ISheet HojaExcel = MeuExcel.GetSheetAt(0);

            int cantidadFilas = HojaExcel.LastRowNum;

            List<VMProduto> lista = new List<VMProduto>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= cantidadFilas; i++)
            {

                IRow fila = HojaExcel.GetRow(i);

                lista.Add(new VMProduto
                {
                    id_Item = fila.GetCell(0).ToString(),
                    nome_Item = fila.GetCell(1).ToString(),
                    qtd_Estoque = fila.GetCell(2).ToString(),
                    preco_por = fila.GetCell(3).ToString(),

                });
            } 

            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, lista);
        }
```

Comment: You want to get the same type of data in excel?  But I didn't find any method to check the type of these data. So I think you might just have to convert the type yourself.

Comment: But how can I do this?

Comment: `ToString()` first, Then convert the type by yourself

Answer (score 0):

Use switch-case may slove your problem, I see you have already finish open the file stream, so here's what can be done to use variable type other than string:

```
private static string GetCellValue(ICell cell)
        {
            if (cell == null)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            switch (cell.CellType)
            {
                case CellType.Blank:
                    return string.Empty;
                case CellType.Boolean:
                    return cell.BooleanCellValue.ToString();
                case CellType.Error:
                    return cell.ErrorCellValue.ToString();
                case CellType.Numeric:
                case CellType.Unknown:
                default:
                    return cell.ToString();
                case CellType.String:
                    return cell.StringCellValue;
                case CellType.Formula:
                    try
                    {
                        HSSFFormulaEvaluator e = new HSSFFormulaEvaluator(cell.Sheet.Workbook);
                        e.EvaluateInCell(cell);
                        return cell.ToString();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        return cell.NumericCellValue.ToString();
                    }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do I need to replace something or include this? I didn't quite understand. I'm off topic GetCell

Comment: Because in this case I'm not passing any parameter from my excel or db, I was confused.

Comment: I don't get it. Maybe I misunderstand your purpose. I thought your purpose is adding your excel file and data to your mvc application then use it, but you have trouble while dividing different data types.

Comment: I can already upload my Excel, the problem is when trying to put the float type and also that I'm using "LastRowNum" and/or "PhysicalNumberOfRows" and it reads the wrong number of lines sometimes and gives an error because it returned line null. Got something to do?